# Azure Sql Server V12 Bulk load error on merge statement

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a query with a simple merge statement to update or insert data in a table:

```
MERGE INTO table_name AS TARGET
USING (
    VALUES (
        :a0
        ,:b0
        ,:c0
        )...
    ) AS SOURCE(A, B, C)
    ON SOURCE.B = TARGET.B
        AND SOURCE.C = TARGET.C
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT (
            A
            ,B
            ,C
            )
        VALUES (
            SOURCE.A
            ,SOURCE.B
            ,SOURCE.C
            );
```

This table has a non clustered index on two columns for uniqueness constraint.
This query works fine on a "Business" database in Azure. After the migration to SQL V12 on an "S2" database, this error happens when i try to merge a huge amount of entries:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load. The bulk data stream was incorrectly specified as sorted or the data violates a uniqueness constraint imposed by the target table. Sort order incorrect for the following two rows: primary key of first row: (A, B, C), primary key of second row: (A, D, E).

It appears that Microsoft knows this issue : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3055799.

But in Azure, i can't update the SQL Server. how can i get it to work ?

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Server V12" ? SQL Server **2012** (which has an internal version number of 11.0) ? Or do you mean SQL Server **2014** (with the internal version number of 12.0) ??

Comment: In the Azure portal, i can see only "V12". "Business" et "web" service plans were on "V2" version. If i execute "SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version';" on a DB, i get this "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8". So, it's an SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Yochanan Rachamim,

Thanks for your answer.

I tried to apply your fix but it has no effect.
After more research, I found a known bug with concurrency : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

I finally solved my problem by adding "WITH (HOLDLOCK)" to the MERGE statement.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and tests, I found a workaround by adding at the end of my query "OPTION (LOOP JOIN, FORCE ORDER);" to bypass the sorting error by modifing the default execution plan.

It also works with "OPTION (MERGE JOIN, FORCE ORDER);" depending on the rows count of the source and the target table.

More infos about the options : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

Comment: To improve my workaround, it works only with "OPTION (MERGE JOIN, FORCE ORDER);". LOOP JOIN produce also an error with latest SQL Server V12 on Azure (not a VM).

Answer (score 0):

we found issue with execution plan generated by the query optimizer. 
this will be fixes very soon.

meanwhile another option to workaround this issue is to disable page_lock on the index.

```
ALTER INDEX [<index name>] ON [<schema>].[<table name>] 
REBUILD WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)
```

with this workaround you do not need to modify your queries.